# Command to Read file in CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Does anyone know of a way to read from a file in CMake, that works in Visual Studio? I have a cross-platform App. in Visual Studio 2017 that compiles with a toolchain in Linux, running in Hyper-V.

I have a simple defined version number in one of my H-files that I would like to read, parse, and append version number to the name of the compiled program (e.g., company_app_1.2.3).

I can't seem to get the file(READ) command to work. Visual Studio is using CMake version 3.11. I assume CMake can do this regardless of the g++ toolchain being used.

Command I tried:

```
#Read version
-file(READ FileNameHere $sValue)
```

Visual Studio Error I get:

```
1>/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `READ'
```

The MakeFile does not have a .txt extension, of follow Visual Studio's naming convention, but I would be willing to rename it if there was an advantage (intellisense available, or some more info about the error).

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: The error you got suggests that you are trying to interpret a file with CMake commands with a shell. This won't work. If you want to interpret a file with CMake, use [CMake scripting mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script): `cmake -P </path/to/script>`.

Comment: Thanks. I will make a script and run the command from there.